# Google tasks API. What parameters to use in TasksRequest.setFields(String fields) method?

Tags: android, google-tasks

I'm building a Android app that sync tasks to google tasks. And i used the Google Tasks APIs. My question is what parameters can I use in TasksRequest.setFields(String fields)? I see the sample code uses "items/title". What if i want to get other fields or what if i want to get multiple fields at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of this string is described here: https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/performance#partial-response

And the APIs Explorer can help you build the string as well using a UI: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer

Answer (score 1):

You must be referring to this snippet of code from the Google Tasks API sample for Android:

```
@Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
try {
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.TasksOperations.List listRequest = service.tasks().list("@default");

  listRequest.setFields("items/title,items/notes,items/completed");
  //listRequest.setFields("items/title");
  List<Task> tasks = listRequest.execute().getItems();
  if (tasks != null) {
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      result.add(task.getTitle());
    }
  } else {
    result.add("No tasks.");
  }
  return result;
} catch (IOException e) {
  tasksSample.handleGoogleException(e);
  return Collections.singletonList(e.getMessage());
} finally {
  tasksSample.onRequestCompleted();
}
```

}

The [documentation](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/tasks/v1/com/google/api/services/tasks/Tasks.Tasklists.Insert.html#setFields%28java.lang.String%29) is very unclear about this, but [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=51) link gave me a clue.

Notice that I use

> "items/title,items/notes,items/completed"

If you get the strings wrong, you will get

> invalidParameter and Invalid field selection note

Comment: @Chris.Zou this answer is more helpful to me than the accepted answer